# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ipanorama is not a function

Tags: jquery, html5, wordpress

**tengo puesto el short code de la siguiente forma**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ipanorama id="893"]');?>
```

pero me salta este error

[image: error]

que podra ser?

asi tengo el head

```
<head>
    <title>OptimusDrone</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Produccion Audivisual con Drone. Nuestra pasión es capturar grandes momentos y lugares desde el aire">
    <link href="index.html" rel="canonical">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/main.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.smoove.js'; ?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans+Extra+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,900" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: debes publicar el codigo! somos programdores no adivinos!

Comment: publique el codigo pero no aparece